# How to substring a string to the before last dot(.) in java?

Tags: java, split

I have a text file data.txt. I want to input the data into a Hashmap and do some datamapping. When ever I hit the value without dot(). I will get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

How to I overcome it by skipping those entry without dot(.).

I created a small snippet to illustrate my problem.

```
  static HashMap<String, String> newList = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String inputFile = "data.txt";
        BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String line;

        while ((line = brInput.readLine()) != null) {
            newList.put(line, "x");
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : newList.entrySet()) {

            String getAfterDot = entry.getKey();
            String[] split = getAfterDot.split("\\.");
            String beforeDot = "";
            beforeDot = getAfterDot.substring(0, getAfterDot.lastIndexOf("."));
            System.out.println(beforeDot);
        }

    }
```

data.txt

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3.5.6
0.2.1
2.2
```

expected result when i print the map(doesnt need to be in order)

```
0
0
0.3.5
0.2
2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the String method `lastIndexOf(int ch)`.

```
int lastIndxDot = st.lastIndexOf('.');
```

`st.substring(0, lastIndxDot);` will be the substring you want. If it returned -1, then there is no '.' in the string.

EDIT:

```
for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: newList.entrySet()) {
    String getAfterDot = entry.getKey();
    int lastIndxDot = getAfterDot.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (lastIndxDot != -1) {
        String beforeDot = getAfterDot.substring(0, lastIndxDot);
        System.out.println(beforeDot);
    }
}
```

Comment: i still get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: @newbieprogrammer which line is it on?

Comment: int lastIndxDot = getAfterDot.lastIndexOf('.');
            beforeDot = getAfterDot.substring(0, lastIndxDot);

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Let me know how it goes

Comment: this work too but any different from the previous answer ? by checking if line contain .

Comment: That check to `contains()` doesn't make a lot of sense since it makes you iterate through the string 2 times instead of once. The `lastIndexOf` method returns -1 if it can't find the character and does only one iteration of the string. Hence, it will always be faster than using `contains` to see if the string contains a `.`.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Just to be sure. The edit worked, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it should work:

```
static HashMap < String, String > newList = new HashMap < > (); 
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String inputFile = "input";
    BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = brInput.readLine()) != null) {

        newList.put(line, "x");
    }

    for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: newList.entrySet()) {

        String getAfterDot = entry.getKey();
        if (getAfterDot.contains(".")) {
            String[] split = getAfterDot.split("\\.");
            String beforeDot = "";
            beforeDot = getAfterDot.substring(0, getAfterDot.lastIndexOf("."));
            System.out.println(beforeDot);
        }
    }

}
```

I got this output with above code:

```
0
0
2
0.3.5
0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check to see if the string has a dot before by using  getAfterDot.contains(".") before invoking the substring function on the string.

```
static HashMap<String, String> newList = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String inputFile = "data.txt";
    BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = brInput.readLine()) != null) {
        newList.put(line, "x");
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : newList.entrySet()) {
        String getAfterDot = entry.getKey();
        String[] split = getAfterDot.split("\\.");
        String beforeDot = "";
        if(getAfterDot.contains(".")){
            beforeDot = getAfterDot.substring(0, getAfterDot.lastIndexOf("."));
            System.out.println(beforeDot);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @newbieprogrammer, _for performance_, get `lastindexOf()` and check it if greater than -1 instead of checking with `contains()` and getting last index after that

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `String.replaceAll()` with a regex which extracts out the portion of the string coming before the period (if the period exists).

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : newList.entrySet()) {
    String getAfterDot = entry.getKey();
    String beforeDot = getAfterDot.replaceAll("(.*)\\..*", "$1");
    System.out.println(beforeDot);
}
```

Comment: Thought I'd point this out if you overlooked. `lastIndexOf` actually returns -1 if the character is not found. So, you dont have to make a repeat iteration by calling contains. Just thought I would let you know.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Please review my updated answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] lines = new String[]{"0", "0.1", "0.2", "0.3.5.6", "0.2.1", "2.2"};
    for (String line : lines) {
        int lastIndexOf = line.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (lastIndexOf > -1) {
            line = line.substring(0, lastIndexOf);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did the array come from?

Comment: @DebosmitRay, **lines** is initialized for example, same as your **data.txt** file content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using libraries, you don't need to re-invent the wheel:

```
beforeDot = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(getAfterDot, ":");
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBeforeLast-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score -2):

I just thought I would point that this can be done in a single line of code:

```
foo.substringAfterLast(".")
```

Comment: Not in JavaScript